# How can I display a HTML page in discord using a bot with python?

Tags: python, html, discord

I'd like to display an embed  with a picture using HTML, but I couldnt find anything online using python to do it. Is that even possible? if it is I would love an explanation.

I tried searching, couldnt find anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense, sounded like a ChatGPT generated answer... AFAIK you can't get HTML embeds on Discord (which is a pain in the arse as it could make the experience much more enjoyable for bot users). One way you could tackle this though is by generating a picture of the content you want to be sent stored on a server you have access to and have the bot share said picture. Lots of cons here, but that's the best I figured out. Good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).